# Dynamic provider for a Marshalling web service outbound gateway

Tags: spring, web-services, marshalling, spring-integration

Is it possible to set a dynamic provider for a Marshalling web service outbound gateway?

I mean, if I try for example: http://100.0.0.1 and it not works, I would like to try http://100.0.0.2 instead

My current configuration:

```
MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gw = new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(provider, jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Since `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway` allows to inject `DestinationProvider`, you feel free to provide any custom implementation.

For your `fault-tolerant` use-case you should do: `new URLConnection(url).connect()` to test connection to the target server in that your `DestinationProvider` implementation.

**UPDATE**

> But If I how can I test new URLConnection(url).connect() if I have https credentials, certificate or any kind of security

Well, another good solution from the Spring Integration is `load-balancing` and several subscribers to the same `DirectChannel`:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel wsChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel(null);
}
```

to switch of the default `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy`.
And after that you can have several `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="wsChannel")`. When the first one is fail, the message is sent to the second and so on, until the good result or the fall for each URL.

Comment: In my configuration, I am creating the gateway as a Bean with: "@Bean @ServiceActivator" MessageHandler wsOutboundGateway(). If I set another gateway, how can I define which bean should be executed? Do you have an example of DestinationProvider?

Comment: If you have several `wsOutboundGateway` `@Bean`s with ` @ServiceActivator` for different URLs you should use `@Router` upstream to determine which URL is available now.

Comment: But If I how can I test new URLConnection(url).connect() if I have https credentials, certificate or any kind of security

Comment: Nice!. Definitely this a very elegant solution.